# Rails 4: Permitted parameter hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, parameters

My params are as follows:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"...",
 "consult_stat"=>
    {"0"=>
        {"employee_id"=>"1",
         "consults"=>"7",
         "signed"=>"8"},
     "1"=>
        {"employee_id"=>"2",
         "consults"=>"5",
         "signed"=>"6"}
     },
 "commit"=>"Submit Consultation Stats"}
```

**How do I permit the nested hash with dynamic keys?**

Comment: you can use nested attributes.

Comment: I keep getting a `ForbiddenAttributeError`

Answer (score 0):

This is quite simple you can achieve it as

```
params.require(:consult_stat).permit(:employee_id,:consults,:signed)
```